# Спесь, надменность, высокомерие, кичливость, заносчивость, гордыня, гонор, тщеславие, чванство

Tags: выбор-слов, лексика

Помогите найти четкое объяснение этих слов, чтобы были ясны различия между ними. Более-менее подробно из словарей написано лишь у Даля. Есть что-то более полное и понятное?

Comment: Ну, почему же "лишь у Даля"?
http://slovari.yandex.ru/спесь/правописание/
http://slovari.yandex.ru/надменность/правописание/
http://slovari.yandex.ru/высокомерие/правописание/
http://slovari.yandex.ru/кичливость/правописание/
http://slovari.yandex.ru/заносчивость/правописание/
http://slovari.yandex.ru/гордыня/правописание/
http://slovari.yandex.ru/гонор/правописание/
http://slovari.yandex.ru/тщеславие/правописание/
http://slovari.yandex.ru/чванство/правописание/

Comment: Лишь у Даля расписаны оттенки значений, там прямо описываются отличия надменности от высокомерия, кичливости, например.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне показалось интересным, что, прочитав толкование этих слов у Ожегова, я увидела, что все они как бы связаны по кругу - одно слово определяется через пару других слов, дальше то же самое, так что можно вернуться к исходному слову. Даже возник вопрос: а зачем языку нужно так много слов, чтобы определить качество человека, которое в принципе можно свести к одной мысли: "Я лучше других"? Но должны же эти слова чем-то различаться, и я думаю, что таким различием может быть ОБЛАСТЬ ИХ ПРИМЕНЕНИЯ, а также ХАРАКТЕР нашего отрицательного героя.

Вот, например, он ходит в начальниках - значит,  чванный и спесивый. Вот он выбирает круг своего общения, считая, что не каждый достоин его внимания, - тогда он высокомерный и надменный. А если он писатель, поэт, артист, то тщеславный, самолюбивый  и кичливый. Хорошего собеседника из него тоже не получится, потому что он заносчив, непомерно горделив и любит говорить только о себе. Или не говорит, но держится напыщенно,  с гонором, своим поведение демонстрируя свое превосходство.

Answer (score 1):

Превознесение себя над другими, мнение, что ты чем-то лучше остальных, пренебрежение по отношению к другим.

Comment: Это слишком поверхностно, не дает возможности для градации и разделения.

Answer (score 0):

;1. Пройдите по предложенным мной ссылкам, найдите уже эти слова в разных словарях:

**Надменный**

МАС: Пренебрежительно, свысока относящийся к людям; высокомерный.

**ВЫСОКОМЕ́РИЕ**

БАС: Уверенность в своём превосходстве, надменное, пренебрежительное отношение к окружающим.

;2. Наморщите ум и сравните два определения самостоятельно. Тогда, вычеркнув общее, увидите, что **высокомерие** - это "уверенность в своём превосходстве", а **надменность** - "свысока-отношение-к-людям" (а "пренебрежительность" входит в оба определения).

;3. Не обращайте внимания на некоторую надменность моего стиля (но, ceterum censeo, попытайтесь уже что-то сделать самостоятельно! ну всё же есть в словарях, надо только открыть и сравнить).

Comment: В словарях смотрел. Исчерпывающего ответа в них не нашел. Более или менее полно и ясно было у Даля, но я думал найти что-то еще более развернутое.

Comment: Вы уж тогда определитесь, чего хотите. В вопросе было пожелание "найти четкое объяснение этих слов, чтобы были ясны различия между ними". Я показал вам алгоритм, как можно обнаружить эти различия. Это и будет "наиболее понятным". 

А "более полное" можно надёжно получить только одним (проверенным!) способом - поиском примеров в литературных произведениях русских классиков. Это большая и сложная работа, быстрого готового решения тут нет.

Answer (score -1):

В английском языке оба слова тоже есть, и люди так же задаются вопросом о разнице, и ответ одного из англоговорящих очень порадовал своей простотой:

Человек высокомерный – необязательно надменен, а человек надменный – обязательно высокомерен.

Высокомерность (arrogant) – это неоправданное преувеличение собственного значения/талантов/навыков и т. д.

Надменность (haughty) – это презрение по отношению к другим, признание других людей ничтожными.

Так что глупо упрекать русский язык за наличие этих "одинаковых" слов, так как они просто-напросто имеют разное значение, и общее у них – только частный момент.

Comment: «Есть что-то более полное и понятное (в словарях — sh.)?» Такой был вопрос. Конкретный.

Comment: Могу посоветовать лишь почитать хорошие английские словари. Определения там порой очень хороши. Главное - это преодолеть заблуждение, что англ. беден т.к ёмок. Это не одно и то же. В английском, полагаю, за редким исключением есть все те же слова и, разумеется, определения к ним. Так же можно попробовать форумы, где англоговорящие обсуждают эти же слова.

Comment: Тяга к английскому? Будем Даля переводить и дополнять? У автора вопроса другие проблемы, и они конкретны. А в ответе у Вас: «...глупо упрекать русский язык за наличие...» и т. д. Читайте вопрос, ведь он не о том.

Comment: Насчёт упрёка русского языка это был комментарий одному из ответивших выше, а не к автору. Да и то просто к слову.